# datatable pagination not working in erb

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, pagination, datatables, erb

I am using datatable. it is working fine
for this

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>abcd</th>
      <th>def</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>123</td>
      <td>456</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

but for this it is not working

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>abcd</th>
      <% if !session[:user].nil? %>
      <th>def</th>
      <% end %>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>123</td>
      <% if !session[:user].nil? %>
      <td>456</td>
      <% end %>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

and one more thing...only pagination is not working ..else everything is working..export, search bar

Comment: can you please elaborate on "not working"? what do you expect to see? what do you see instead? Can you tell us what database has to do with session-user? Unrelated: Are you using something like devise for user login? if so - can you use `user_signed_in?` instead of your custom check against session?

Comment: this is an example, actually in this td tag there is a button which enable row for editing...therefore i want to disable it to unauthenticated user

Comment: Did you use `Devise` ?

Comment: @ShubhamAgrawal - yes... but this example does not provide enough information to help us figure out what is wrong with your actual code. There is nothing wrong with the code in the example you give... so you have to give us more information - specifically, you have to tell us what you mean by "something is wrong"... because right now you're making us guess what is wrong. Please tell us more or we literally cannot help you.